# 海外からの注文エラー

Tags: paypal

決済にペイパルを使って管理しているECで、海外の特定ユーザーから決済がいつもエラーになります。

エラーコード:10736
メッセージ:A match of the Shipping Address City, State, and Postal Code failed.

```
METHOD: SetExpressCheckout
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION: Sale
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE: US
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE: JPY
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME: ＜アルファベット＋半角スペース＞
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM: ＜数字＋ハイフン＞
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP: 95051
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE: CA
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY: ＜英数＋.＋半角スペース＞
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT: 7100
MAXAMT: 7100
LOCALECODE: US
SOLUTIONTYPE: Mark
ADDROVERRIDE: 1
ALLOWNOTE: 0
```

この情報でわかる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

welcartでも問題があがっています。
http://www.welcart.com/development/mantisbt/view.php?id=829

“SHIPTOCITY”には、その州内に実際に存在する市（Street Name、番地などは含まない）の名前を指定します（例えば”San Jose”）とあるので。このあたり疑ってみてください。

0にすればノーチェックらしいですが。そうしていいのかは、私では判断できません。

Comment: kimaihack66さん
>NOSHIPPING=1で配送先住所非表示になります。

Norikaz Ishiiさん
>0にすればノーチェックらしい

お返事遅くなりましたがそれぞれ確認してみます！

Answer (score 1):

まず、

```
""A match of the Shipping Address City, State, and Postal Code failed.""
```

はアメリカの郵便番号にあたるzipcodeとパラメータとして渡された街の名前が違う場合に出ると思われます。

次に、

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP: 95051
```

の場合には、

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=Santa Clara
```

を渡さないとエラーが出ます。

ペイパルではSetExpressCheckout経由でshipping addressを渡すのは必須ではありませんので、
ECの方ですでに配送先住所を管理されている場合は住所を渡さないように変更されても構いません。

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

NOSHIPPING=1で配送先住所非表示になります。